# Can access service from outside cluster, but not from inside

Tags: kubernetes, port

I am stuck on a problem that has me fairly baffled. I have two Kubernetes services, let's call them `frontend` and `middleware` that do the following:

`frontend` serves a website and sits behind an ingress controller that exposes it on port 80.

`middleware` accepts REST requests from `frontend` and passes it back the requested information (from a database in the background).

My problem is as follows:

If I run `middleware` on a Kubernetes cluster and expose it as a LoadBalancer and then run `frontend` locally (configured to connect to the LoadBalancer's external IP) everything works correctly. However, if I run `frontend` on the Kubernetes cluster (whether configured to connect to the LoadBalancer's external IP, or to use the internal IP) instead of locally I can connect to the frontend, but the frontend fails to fetch the data from `middleware`, i.e. it is unable to connect to it.

I am somewhat at a loss to why this would be. In both cases `middleware` has exactly the same configuration and I can't see how `frontend`'s configuration would influence it.

I would be grateful for any ideas on what could be wrong with the configuration.

Below are the relevant YAML files:

```
# middleware
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: middleware
  labels:
    app: middleware
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: middleware
  template:
    metadata:
      name: middleware-app
      labels:
        app: middleware
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: middleware-app
          image: myrepo.com/middleware:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: middleware-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: middleware
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
---
# frontend
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      name: frontend-app
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:      
      containers:
        - name: frontend-app
          image: myrepo.com/frontend:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: frontend-service  
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
    - port: 80
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
...
```

**EDIT:**

I've spent most of the day tearing away ingress and authentication layers and slowly putting them back one by one, with the following result:

Let's say I have an ingress as follows, which essentially just passes the user along from either the ingress external ip (something like `xxxxaaaaabbbbbzzz.elb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` he types that into his browser) or from a custom registered domain (i.e my.domain.com), that has been set up to forward to that external ip.

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend-service
              servicePort: 80
    - host: my.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend-service
              servicePort: 80
```

What I find completely incomprehensible, is that if I go to `xxxxaaaaabbbbbzzz.elb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` directly in my browser, then the queries to `middleware` work correctly. However, if I go there via `my.domain.com` they do not. How is that possible? Both of those addresses are just forwarding to `frontend-service`, I cannot see why they would interact differently with `middleware`.

**EDIT EDIT**

Also as additional information: logging into the `frontend` container and calling `curl http://middleware_ip_address:8081` as well as `curl http://middleware_elb_address:8081` both work. `curl http://middleware_elb_address:8081` also works from outside the cluster.

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**

I works when accessing via `http://my.domain.com` but not when accessing via `https://my.domain.com`. Certificate currently not set up. Could that be the cause?

Comment: Can you share how the frontend service is connecting to middleware service? Is it using a http client and an IP, or some other means?

Comment: it is a javascript application that connects to it via a static ip configured as `http://the_ip_address:8081`

Comment: did you `curl http://the_ip_address:8081` its work fine ?

Comment: As I already said, running the frontend locally works, so the backend is definitely up and reachable. The frontend just doesn't seem to be able to reach if deployed on Kubernetes as shown in the question

Comment: This is not that clear to me now. Can you confirm that both services deployed inside kubernetes are accessible outside using `curl http://the_ip_address:8081` & `curl http://the_ip_address:80`?

Comment: Can you add details about your k8s cluster? What Host os and what tools were used for cluster deployment?

Comment: It is an EKS cluster